# unable to drag and drop ImageView in grid layout in android studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, grid-layout, android-studio-2.3

is it form android studio 2.3+ google has changed how to use grid layout. I was trying to make a tic tac toe game and i made a 3X3 grid layout but i am unable to put ImageView into it..!!

This is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.neerajm.tictacbasic.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.797"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

</GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to Create Class and inside main activity make an object that class And put in your grid layout

class Bdfd  extends ImageView

MainActivity 
gridlayout gl
Bdfd   object=new Bdfd ;
gl.AddView(bdfd);

If I understand your question.It Must to be something like that..